# SVN Checkout error on large repositories

Tags: windows-7, svn, centos6, tortoisesvn

I wonder if anyone can help me. We have recently migrated our Subversion repository from a VisualSVN Server on Windows to a subversion server on CentOS.

The migration was succesfull however we are getting the following error message

```
Error REPORT of svn'/svn/MangoRepository/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read chunk size:
Error connection was closed by server (http://servername)
```

Now the workaround for this is simply to perform a update on the repo and it will contine where is left off.

Im just wondering if anyone was a permanent fix for this as it can be quite frustrating to repeat my self to 60-70 developers.

Comment: Getting the message, when exactly? If the repository URL changed, users should relocate their working copies or checkout new ones. BTW see the possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772894/updating-from-svn-repository-returns-could-not-read-chunk-size-error

Comment: Can you test whether the error occurs with the command line `svn` client?  That will narrow down whether the problem is the Tortoise or the server.  And can you provide info on how you've configured the server to serve the SVN repo?

Comment: Check the logs on the server.  See if it says anything about why it closed the connection.

Comment: I get the message when performing a checkout, i have tried checking out using tortoise and svn client on the server itself and it comes up with the same error at the same place.

Comment: So we using CentOS 6.3 with apache, apache is configured to authenticate against active directory using kerberos. I have checked the logs and it shows the following error "Error writing base64 data: Software caused connection abort".

Comment: On top of this i peformed a svn dump on the repo and i set up a temp windows server with visual svn, i then loaded the same repo into this server and tried a checkout and im getting no error messages. So it seems to me that there is something in the CentOS, Apache configuration that is dropping the tcp connection. i have tired looking at help pages to try and optimize apache but im having no luck. has anyone come across anything like this before.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a similar error message when dealing with migrating from a case-insensitive filesystem (windows) to a case sensitive one (Most Unixes). Is there a chance that you have a file called Default in some contexts and default in others?

Comment: The default in the URL isn't a file.  It's a special URL for Subversion.  So I don't think this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

SVN checkout send requests and receive a lot of tiny files. So it may create hundreds or thousands connections at the same time.

#### We have trouble with it in previous time, this is what we did:

- **Reduce the network bandwidth** to decrease number of connection in a short time.
- **Adjust the firewall** accept more connections.